# How to constrain Go's grpc go routine number

Tags: go, client, grpc

Is there anyway that I can constrain the number of go routines in grpc client? I have a go application that uses grpc client and I found that there are quite a few amount of go routines being created and kept growing.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: gRPC starts every request in a goroutine. if the number of incoming rpc requests increases, so is the goroutines. I would suggest you take a look at your rpc function to minimise your latency.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you concerned about the number of go routines? What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: The actual problem is that as  vedhavyas described, gRPC starts a new goroutine for every request. When the latency is high my goroutine number just keeps piling up. I guess the real problem is in the latency of the rpc call itself. Just out of curiosity, I wonder what is the behavior on C++ gRPC client. Does it have some sort of thread pooling?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to limit grpc goroutines, there is no way, but I doubt there is any point in limiting goroutine number. What if you reached your limit and another request come?

You could use a semaphore like pattern at the beginning of your handler so you limit to N concurrent requests. Additional requests will wait for other requests to finish before they start processing (But there is more that N goroutines, only N of them are working).

[Here](http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/semaphores) is an implementation of semaphores using channel.